# Autocomment from review ending up on both question and answer

Tags: bug, review, comments

Something rather strange happened recently. An auto comment from the LQP review queue ended up on the question as well as the (now deleted) answer where it belonged:

[image: Screenshot of comments.]

Is this a bug? Some kind of issue with a moderator deleting the answer while it is in review? Or what happened here?

- [The question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/146688/98538)
- [The answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/146689/98538) (only for 10K+ users)
- [The review](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/91574)

Comment: I do not think this is a bug. As written in the answer the whole conversation was simply moved to the comment sections : _converted to a comment by AviD♦_. The comment from Jedi has been simply moved as well.

Comment: Yeah, as @Xavier59 said, I moved that answer to a comment. I didn't realize at the time there was that auto-comment on it... Thanks for noticing, I cleaned it up.

Comment: Ah, so it is just the moderation tools that moves all the comments along with it? I thought I had found a bug. Had I realized it was so simple I would just have flagged instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Xavier59 and @AviD explains in comments, this is not a bug.

When a moderator converts an answer to a comment, all the comments to the answer are moved along with it. In this case the moderator didn't notice the autocomment, and it was automatically moved to the question. So nothing strange going on at all.